# Why isn't my tellraw command working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to add missions to my museum in Minecraft, and i tried adding an extra text part to my /tellraw message. The command is below, copy/pasted from a command block:

> tellraw @p {"text":"(Mission #1)","color":"blue","extra":[{"text":"There are FungusKing_III heads hidden around the museum. See if you can find them all!","color":"dark_blue""}}

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There is a `]` missing. Not sure if that's the only thing though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix 'Invalid JSON' errors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304990/how-do-i-fix-invalid-json-errors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You opened the `extra` list with a square bracket, but then didn't close it.
2. You have two quotation marks at the end of `"dark_blue""`.

Fixing those, the command will work:

```
tellraw @p {"text":"(Mission #1)","color":"blue","extra":[{"text":"There are FungusKing_III heads hidden around the museum. See if you can find them all!","color":"dark_blue"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem completely! Do you think i should use a tellraw generator next time?

Comment: @FungusKing I'd recommend using one (e.g: [this](http://minecraft.tools/en/tellraw.php)), as it makes writing the JSON a lot easier and less error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would use this, it's easier:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"(Mission #1)","color":"blue"},{"text":"Their are FungusKing_III Heads hidden around the museum, see if you can find them all!","color":"dark_blue"}}]
```

That would work.